# How can i rotate the character head when moving the mouse cursor around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

But the player should look around with the head i think in the world space. For example if i move the mouse cursor around and it's pointing on a mountain the player should look at the mountain. But the main goal is to rotate the head whe just moving the mouse around in the game window while the game is running.

Maybe i also don't need so many variables of rotating, speed, x,y ? Maybe i can use less variables for all of that. I want to keep the other parts in the script and to add the head part.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit with zoom")]
public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

    public float yMinLimit = 3.0f;//-20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    public Transform boneToRotate;
    int speed;
    float friction;
    float lerpSpeed;
    private float xDeg;
    private float yDeg;
    private Quaternion fromRotation;
    private Quaternion toRotation;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 3;
        friction = 3f;
        lerpSpeed = 3f;

        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        x = angles.y;
        y = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
        {
            xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * friction;
            yDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * friction;
            fromRotation = boneToRotate.rotation;
            toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
            boneToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);

            Debug.Log("Mouse Freedom");
        }

        if (target && Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

            y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distance -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

The script is attached to the Main Camera.
In the boneToRotate variable i dragged the EthanHead from the ThirdPersonController.

The part i just added now for rotating the head is:
In the top:

```
public Transform boneToRotate;
int speed;
float friction;
float lerpSpeed;
private float xDeg;
private float yDeg;
private Quaternion fromRotation;
private Quaternion toRotation;
```

In Start:

```
speed = 3;
friction = 3f;
lerpSpeed = 3f;
```

In Update:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
            {
                xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * friction;
                yDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * friction;
                fromRotation = boneToRotate.rotation;
                toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
                boneToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);

                Debug.Log("Mouse Freedom");
            }
```

But it's not working at all. The head is not rotating at all with the mouse cursor.

Comment: have you tried witha LookAt()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize your variables with proper values -

```
void Start()
{
    speed = 3;
    friction = 3f;
    lerpSpeed = 3f;
    xDeg = 0f;
    yDeg = 0f;
    fromRotation = boneToRotate.rotation;
    toRotation = boneToRotate.rotation;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then move lerp function out of the if condition -

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
{
    xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * friction;
    yDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * friction;
    fromRotation = boneToRotate.rotation;
    toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);

    Debug.Log("Mouse Freedom");
}
boneToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
```